# msirjh32.dll could not be found on startup

Tags: windows-7, boot, dll

Every time I start my PC, I get this error message:

> There was a problem starting msirjh32.dll
>
> The specified module could not be found.

It does this every time I start, and it's been happening for a while now. The thing is that the computer works just fine, it gives me this error message but after that I see no problems whatsoever, I can do everything I should be able to. Also note that this only happens when *starting* the computer, not when resuming from hibernation or standby.

The PC is running Windows 7 Ultimate 64-bit, and is fairly strong (2.30GHz CPU, 4.00MB RAM). It's not a problem really since as I said it doesn't seem to cause any problems, but I'm curious as to why the error comes up, and Google yields no results (literally 0).

Comment: Did you spell the filename correctly? Google returns nothing for `msirjh32.dll`. You most likely have an application that was removed, but left an entry in your startup folder or registry section. Use SysInternals' Autoruns to look for what's causing it.

Comment: i can state one thing go to ms-config select start-up method as diagnostic startup which will load all basic windows services and if the error message doesnt happened means there is no problem in your windows and the error maybe caused due to internal startup applications

Comment: @Randolph I'm 90% sure I spelt the filename correctly, I can't copy and paste it but I looked ever so carefully and I'm pretty sure I've got it right. And yeah, as I said Google returns nothing. I think that your idea that it's from an old app is probably right, I'll try that program you mentioned. Otherwise I'll try vignesh's suggestion.

Comment: Autoruns will include all the entries that msconfig does.